# TypeScript `.d.ts` file not copied to output, causing broken reference

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

In my Typescript files, I import a type from the declaration file just like this.

In example.ts:

```
import { AnyObject } from './index;
export const obj: AnyObject = {};
```

And then when I run the command to compiler like this.
`tsc -d`

It will generate a example.js and example.d.ts but not index.d.ts.

In the example.d.ts:

```
import { AnyObject } from './index';
export declare const obj: AnyObject;
```

Obviously it can't find the index.d.ts module.So I want to know how to solve this problem, thanks.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
    ],
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "./packages/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to tweak your TS config settings. Post your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: OK.I already post it.

Comment: What is `AnyObject`? Can you post a minimal code so I can reproduce your issue?

Comment: In index.d.ts:`export interface AnyObject {
  [prop: string]: any
}`.

Comment: I update the code which will show the problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your source directory has `example.ts` and `index.d.ts`, and your output directory has `example.js` and `example.d.ts` but nothing for `index`, so the reference in `example.d.ts` is broken.  Based on [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5112) (found in a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+copy+%22d.ts%22+to+output+directory)), the behavior is intentional and I don't think there's another solution than renaming `index.d.ts` to `index.ts` or using a separate tool to copy it to your output directory.